# Mongoose find() and count() at the sametime

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Imagine below sample datas:

**TestDB**

```
  {
    "_id": "56caf46a97bbe1b24163ef81",
    "age": 40,
    "eyeColor": "red"
  },
  {
    "_id": "56caf46a460b1d91a0d882d8",
    "age": 29,
    "eyeColor": "green"
  },
  {
    "_id": "56caf46afd859790720a2bb8",
    "age": 27,
    "eyeColor": "brown"
  },
```

I have to render:

- TestDB.eyeColor (red, green, brown)
- The number of TestDB documents (3)

to view page at the sametime.

I'm using express, so I should use res.render('view', {data}).

I tried like that :

```
app.get('/somePage', function(req, res, next){
    TestDB.find({}, function(err, dbs){
        res.render('view', {'eyeColor' : dbs.eyeColor })
    }).count(function(err, count){

       // How can I render this 'count' to view at the sametime?
       // If I render at here, I can't use above dbs.eyeColor, 
       // Same, If I render at above, I can't use count. 

       // Ok, There is a way to separate find() and count()
       // And make a variable and then render with this, 
       // Should I do like that? I think there must be easy way. 



    })
});
```

Comment: Also, as just stated `dbs` is an "array"! So `dbs.eyeColor` is invalid. Instead you want, `res.render('view', { "eyeColor": dbs.map(function(el) { return el.eyeColor }) })`. Or some variant thereof.

Answer (score 0):

If the `eyeColor` could be distinct, with [`distinct`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-distinct) could be better as following. It will return the `eysColor` as one array `['red', 'green', 'brown']`, then render it to view directly, the `count` could be retrieved through `colors.length`.

```
TestDB.distinct('eyeColor', function(error, colors) {
    res.render('view', {'eyeColor' : colors})
});
```

If the `eyeColor` could be duplicate values, then could be done as Blackes shown in the comments

```
TestDB.find({}, function(error, vals) {
    res.render('view', {'eyeColor' : vals.map(function(v) {return v.eyeColor;});})
});
```